# How to access database id number of combobox selected index using Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am developing a project called higher education management system using Entity Framework in C#. In the combobox1 object, I select a university from my universities table in my database. I also select the department name from my departments table in my database in another combobox2 object.

How can I access the id number of the university and department that I selected in the combobox object using Entity Framework?

There is an instance code here. naming is a bit different.

```
private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    comboBox1.DataSource = db.universiteler.Select(u => u.uni_ad).ToList();
}       
   
private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        comboBox2.Items.Clear();
        comboBox3.Items.Clear();

        universiteler SecilenUni = db.universiteler.Where(x => x.uni_ad == comboBox1.Text).FirstOrDefault();

        foreach (fakulteler item in db.fakulteler.Where(x => x.uni_id == SecilenUni.uni_id).ToList())
        {
            comboBox2.Items.Add(item.fakulte_ad);
        }
     }
     catch (Exception)
     {
     }
 }

 private void comboBox2_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     try
     {
         comboBox3.Items.Clear();

         fakulteler SecilenFakulte = db.fakulteler.Where(x => x.fakulte_ad == comboBox2.Text).FirstOrDefault();

         foreach (bolumler item in db.bolumler.Where(x => x.fakulte_id == SecilenFakulte.fakulte_id).ToList())
         {
             comboBox3.Items.Add(item.bolum_ad);
         }
     }
     catch (Exception)
     {
     }
}
```

What do you recommend? Please help!

Comment: Can you include the relevant models please ? At least for me it is not clear what you mean with university and department. Because i do not speak the language i can only guess that universiteler could mean university